# Does a <StackLayout> have some default padding or spacing?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I tried to enclose two StackLayout's inside another StackLayout, but seems like there is some additional padding somewhere.  Is there a default padding and if so how could I remove it for the outer StackLayout?

Comment: Yes, there's a default `Spacing="6"` on StackLayouts. I'm just not 100% sure on the number though.

Comment: Based on the documentation the default spacing in StackLayout is 6.0 => https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Xamarin.Forms.StackLayout.Spacing/. If you want/need to remove it just set it to 0.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's no Padding.

There's a Spacing of 6 between each item (Horizontal or Vertical depending on Orientation).